# Add information to beginning of file using a BAT process, but keep file name convention

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am new to Stackoverflow, so I hope I am posting this in the correct area.  I have been searching for an answer to my question for quite a while.  I am attempting to add some information to the beginning of a file.  The file that needs the information has a dynamic file name (Never the same, except for first 5 characters).  You can see in my code the information I am needing in my file.  The name of the file original file is LBL043629201313114512.DTA.  The consist about the file name is "LB04xxxx.  The XXXX is what I am searching for to make sure I grab the correct file.

I need the output to be the original file name (LBL......DTA) with the collected data at the beginning of the file.  Any help would be great.

```
set /p STORE=Please enter store number:
set /p NAME=Please enter name:
set /p ADDRESS=Please enter address:
set /p CITY=Please enter address:
set /p STATE=Please enter State:
set /p ZIP=Please enter ZIP:
set /p SPECIAL=Add any Special Instructions:
(
    echo %NAME%
    echo %ADDRESS% 
    echo %CITY% %STATE% %ZIP%
    echo %SPECIAL%
) > address.txt
copy address.txt+LBL04%STORE%*.DTA=test.txt
```

Comment: Everything is clear except what your intent is for the last line (the `copy` statement). `copy` makes a copy of the specified file (in this case `address.txt`), and the `+` means "appended by" (not a `string` concatenation, but a `file content` concatenation), and the `=` isn't valid in a copy statement at all (it's presence causes an "invalid syntax error"). In other words, `copy file1+file2` results in a single file that has the content of `file1` followed by `file2`'s content. In order to name that new single file, you just specify another filename: `copy file1+file2 file3`.

Comment: 'copy file1+file2=file3' surprisingly works (at least on XP)

Comment: `=` is one of the default delimiters in windows cmd.

Answer (score 0):

just append two lines at the end:

```
del /q LBL04%STORE%*.DTA 
ren test.txt LBL04%STORE%*.DTA
```

Be sure, you don't need the original .DTA again (better, make a backup as long as you test your script

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%i IN (store name address 
            city state zip 
        special target) DO (SET %%i=)
set /p STORE=Please enter store number:
set /p NAME=Please enter name:
set /p ADDRESS=Please enter address:
set /p CITY=Please enter address:
set /p STATE=Please enter State:
set /p ZIP=Please enter ZIP:
set /p SPECIAL=Add any Special Instructions:
FOR %%i IN (store name address 
            city state zip 
        special) DO IF NOT DEFINED %%i (SET %%i= )
(
    ECHO.%NAME%
    ECHO.%ADDRESS% 
    ECHO.%CITY% %STATE% %ZIP%
    ECHO.%SPECIAL%
) > address.txt
FOR /f %%i IN (
  'dir /b /a-d /o-d lbl04%store%*.dta'
  ) DO IF NOT DEFINED target SET target=%%i
IF NOT DEFINED target ECHO LBL04%STORE%*.DTA NOT found&GOTO :EOF
copy address.txt+%target%=test.txt >nul
MOVE test.txt %target% >nul

type %target%
```

Obviously, you should try this against a copy of your real data first, not your live data.

The first `FOR` ensures that the variable names in the list are removed from the environment so that if they have an existing value then pressing `enter` at any of the prompts, that value would have been retained.

The second `FOR` loop ensures that each of the entered variables HAS a value. Note that `target` is NOT included in this group. There is a space between the `=` and the `)`.

With a simple `SET` instruction, SPACES are significant. The syntax `(SET var=)` or equivalently, `SET "var="` ensures that the variable `var` is set to [nothing]. The problem with `SET var=` is that some editors leave terminal spaces on the line and under those circumstances, `var` will be set to those terminal spaces - and they're a little difficult to see. Also, `SET var =...` will set the variable "`var`" not the variable "`var`" - but that's a whole 'nother story.

Note that the `ECHO` statements now have a dot directly following the `ECHO`. The statement `ECHO` or `ECHO` will cause `ECHO` to report its state, and `ECHO is off` would appear in the output. Adding the "`.`" gives `ECHO` something to chew on and it produces the line content beyond the `.`

The `dir` instruction in the next statement produces a directory list in `/b` basic form (filenames only) `/a-d` and no directory names `/o-d` in reverse-date order. The `FOR /f` is a mechanism for reading the output of the `dir /b ...` instruction, line-by-line. The contents of the next line of "input" read is applied to `%%i` each iteration. Therefore, the first filename matching `LBL04%STORE%*.DTA` encountered will be SET into `target` and  since `target` is now set, any further lines will be ignored because of the `if not defined` gate.

If there were no matching files, `target` would not be defined (it was deleted in the very first `for` loop) so it's possible to produce an error message.

Otherwise, concatenate the files to `test.txt` and then the `move` statement actually `replaces` the file "`%target%` (which we know exists) with the concatenated version.

The `>nul` on each of these last two lines suppreses the message '1 file copied/moved`

Job done! New file `TYPED` as evidence